# Can i hide or close javascript alert after sometime?

Tags: javascript, time, hide, alert

I need to hide one javascript alert message after 10 seconds.is it possible to achieve this.

Comment: No you cannot.Alert or a Confirm messagebox halts the execution of the script altogether and no part of your code can run afterwards(remember Javascript is single threaded) to close.Also there is no inbuilt API that allows you to close the native popup without the user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't hide it programmatically. You can use customised UI components, like [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to emulate alert and hide it:

```
$("#dialog").dialog();//create customized alert
//do something
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog('close');//hide it after 10 seconds
}, 10000)'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not possible in plain old javascript alert boxes..

But yes, you can definitely use modern custom alert dialog boxes to do so.

Two of the most favourites are as follows :

Bootbox : http://bootboxjs.com/

Malsup Block UI : http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a javascript alert().

To get similar functionality, you could instead show a hidden `<div>` which you can hide after a delay.

To do this, use something like

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display="block";
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display="none";
}, 10000);
```

which would show the div 'myDIV', wait 10 seconds (10000ms), then hide the div.
You would also need to set 'myDIV' to display none in your css.